# Explain one statement about Stone Space

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, boolean-algebra

In this page [Stone Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) This is no clear for me **"The points in S(B) are the ultrafilters on B, or equivalently the homomorphisms from B to the two-element Boolean algebra"**

> I think I means every ultafilter on B is a homomorphism from B to 2 ?? I will be pleased to see some details about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ultrafilter $U$ in a Boolean algebra $B$ determines a homomorphism $f:B\to2$ that sends all the elements of $U$ to 1 and all the other elements of $B$ to 0. Conversely, a homomorphism $f:B\to2$ determines the ultrafilter $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ in $B$. It is easy to check that these two transformations are inverse to each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation